# Maven : PKIX path building failed

Tags: maven

Maven build throwing this exception

> Failed to execute goal on project mdf-portal-3rdParty: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   com.alu.ipprd.bsm.soa:mdf-portal-3rdParty:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed
>   to collect dependencies at
>   com.alu.ipprd.bsm.soa.portal.soo:common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to
>   read artifact descriptor for
>   com.alu.ipprd.bsm.soa.portal.soo:common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not
>   transfer artifact
>   com.alu.ipprd.bsm.soa.portal.soo:common:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT from/to
>   googlecode.com
>   (http://gmaps4jsf.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gmaps4jsf-repo):
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]

I did not made any single change in pom.xml file ,suddenly after taking update from SVN i am getting this exception.

I will want to know

1. What is the cause of this problem?
2. Is this issue due to anything change in SVN server?
3. Even no any change in local machine why this build fail error?
4. Something wrong with Gmaps4jsf repository ?(May be due to closing of Google code)

Comment: Hello, We had the same problem... I think is related with Gmaps4jsf repository... I have removed <repository>
   <id>googlecode.com</id>
   <url>http://gmaps4jsf.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gmaps4jsf-repo</url>
  </repository> and now it works ok

Comment: Yes right as googlecode going to close any jar wich is park at googlecode creating issue.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add ssl certificate to your jre installation

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37411410/1802348) answer and follow steps!

Step 1 - Get Root CA certificate

Step 2 - install that certificate at jre cacerts file

Comment: Done you think this issue due to gmaps4jsf-repo ?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi gmaps4jsf-repo itself is not issue as it is http it do not give ssl related issues.According to me its dependencies would have https url and hance you are facing such issue.Always post issue with debug logs! just append -X with your maven command and update your answer.

Answer (score 1):

maybe your maven version isnot the proper version. I encounter this problem in 3.2.3. and resolve it in 3.3.9 version.