# Error Java connection HTTPS with SSL certificates

Tags: java, ssl, https, certificate

I have a problem to connect with SSL in Java.

I use java 1.7.80 and S.O. : ubuntu 14.04

My problem is the certificate, even certificates. I have four elements that must be concatenated using the pkcs12 format.

`testservizi.fattura.it.cer`  --> certificate that identifies the remote server

`SDI-11036210158`             --> certificate client

`CAEntratetest.cer`           --> certificate CA

`private.key`                 --> private key

1) Step - convert the file cer into file pem

```
$ openssl x509 -in CAEntratetest.cer -outform PEM -out CAEntratetest.pem
$ openssl x509 -in SDI-11036210158.cer -inform DER -out SDI-11036210158.pem -outform PEM
$ openssl x509 -in testservizi.fatturapa.it.cer -inform DER -out testservizi.fatturapa.it.pem -outform PEM
```

2) Step - union pem files for create chain certificate

```
$ cat CAEntratetest.pem SDI-11036210158.pem testservizi.fatturapa.it.pem > sum_cert.pem
```

3) Step - create p12 file

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -in sum_cert.pem -inkey private.key -out sogei_auth.p12 -name sogei_auth
```

Ok. My first test is to import the p12 file in the browser (Mozilla Firefox) to verify the operation.
The import is successful and at this point I enter the url

https://testservizi.fatturapa.it/ricevi_file

and he answered:

> Hello! This is an Axis2 Web Service!

..perfect works!!

Now I have to make it work with java and I create a test client

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class TestHTTPSClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(new File("C:/testSSL/sogei_auth.p12"), "changeit".toCharArray()).build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext);
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://testservizi.fatturapa.it/ricevi_file");
            System.out.println("executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            try {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                EntityUtils.consume(entity);
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }
}
```

2) Change format keystore in **java.security**, otherwise you can not read the file p12

`keystore.type=jks`

change into

`keystore.type=pkcs12`

3) Start testing in java and I answered with an error

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
...
..
.
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
... 26 more
```

can you help me...

Comment: Where can we get the test certificate for FatturaPA? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you may store in jre cacerts file for permanently solve this issue if runtime certification stuff is not required! Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37108820/1802348) answer for installing certificate to cacerts...

and remove all certification related code form your source! Please clarify if you want to do this runtime only not manually.