# Not able to create Maven project from command prompt because of maven plugins

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, eclipse-oxygen

I have multiple issues with maven. I am placing here one issue.

I have tried to create a maven project from command prompt. I am getting the build failed. I have tried multiple solutions which are suggested in stackoverflow as well as other websites. Below are the environment details,

```
Java - 1.8
Eclipse - Oxygen
Maven - 3.5
OS - Windows
```

When I have ran mvn -version, I am getting the below results in command prompt.

```
D:\WS-Gradle-1563>mvn -version

Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-04T01:09:06+05:30)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_121, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

After conforming maven setup is proper, I have ran this command to create a maven project.

```
D:\WS-Gradle-1563>mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.maven.example -DartifactId=MavenExample -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Here I didn't understand one thing is, why by default the plugin versions are taking like that. Even I have tried from eclipse as well, I am getting errors in pom.xml file related to plugins(Compiler/Resource). I am getting the output is like below.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.3
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.3.2/maven-release-plugin-2.3.2.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.3.2
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/ to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.771 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-30T14:54:49+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/123M
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\A8197\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

In Eclipse I am getting this type of errors.

[image: Error in POM.XML file]

In repository, by default it is downloading the plugins with lover version. I didn't understand where do I disable the configuration and download configured version of plugins. Could you please help me anyone?

I am trying to download the plugins based on [Maven Plugin versions.](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html)

But, not able to do the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven : PKIX path building failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676059/maven-pkix-path-building-failed)

Comment: i am not sure but you can try deleting your .m2 directory and regenerating sample application.

Comment: do you have internet access?  can you access https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom from a browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you behind some corporate network with proxy ?
If so, try adding proxy details to your settings.xml, you should find/create this file in .m2 directory or in your MAVEN_HOME/conf/ directory

```
<proxies>
<proxy>
    <id>proxy-http</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host>your proxy url</host>
    <port>80</port>
    <username>userid if your proxy needs one</username>
    <password>your password</password>
    <nonProxyHosts>if you wish to configure non proxy urls</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
</proxies>
```

Comment: Thanks venkat, I haven't get that details for proxy. But, our company has configured our own repositories. Once, I change in Settings.xml I am able to resolve those issues. Seems, your comment also valid, so +1.